# Scroll map in four directions using buttons instead of screen drag

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I tried to implement Google map API in android. there is an option of "uiScrollGestures" we can set it to true to enable user scroll map using screen drag, Is there anyway to do the same but manually by creating buttons, each button to scroll the map in different direction dynamically just like the default setting? I am just looking for functions names if any?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(float, float)` method from the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#panning_scrolling).

Example:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
// Create a LatLngBounds that includes Australia.
private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(
  new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(-10, 154));

// Sets camera to Australia (example)
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(AUSTRALIA, 5));

// Pans (scrolls) camera by 1.0, 1.0
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(1.0, 1.0));
```

To make directional buttons, scroll the camera by positive and negative values in the appropriate directions.

Comment: Hi Carl, I appreciate your help, but I don't want to move to a specific location, I want to move dynamically in four directions, generally speaking I want to create 4 buttons and apply on each button's listener a movement to a direction.

Comment: @Hussein sorry if it wasn't clear, but the second `moveCamera` method call is the method you want.

Comment: Yes, that what I thought, but unfortunately it is not working for me, I don't know what is happening but the entire app crashed